# Block "document.location" Javascript redirect on one page

Tags: firefox, javascript, blocking

I have a site where I want to prevent the page from reloading using a document.location in a script tag. How can I do this in Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Greasemonkey will not block if the HTML code contains an inline javascript block with a redirect like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "http://google.com";
document.location.replace(url);
</script>
```

Greasemonkey, however can be used to block calls to specific functions -- just overwrite them :). If the above were wrapped into a function call like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect_to(url)
{
  document.location.replace(url);
}
</script>
```

Then you could just redefine the function in Greasemonkey:

```
function redirect_to(url){ return true }
```

**Block inline redirects via Firefox**

Essentially Firefox makes it possible to block any DOM manipulation like `location.href.replace` from a specific site via so-called: [Configurable Security Policies (CAPS)](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/ConfigPolicy.html)

A word of warning: Note that your security settings will then block ALL calls from that domain for `location.href.replace`. If any application makes use of that call, there is no way to allow some of the calls and block others.

**Setting up CAPS to block location.href.replace**

You do not need Greasemonkey for this task. Firefox comes with a built-in capability for allowing/disallowing access to properties/methods of DOM Objects on a per-site basis. It is called Configurable Security Policies (CAPS) and it is described in [1](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/ConfigPolicy.html).

A short guide assuming the simplest case:

1. Close Firefox
2. Locate your profile folder
3. Locate the file user.js within this folder. If it does not exist, create it with a *text* editor (Notepad, vim, etc.)
4. Add the following lines to user.js:

   user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "noframebuster");
   user_pref("capability.policy.noframebuster.sites", "http://www.annoying-site.com");
   user_pref("capability.policy.noframebuster.Location.replace", "noAccess");

Of course, you will have to replace the domain with the one you want to prevent from redirecting your frames.

Find a more thorough explanation from my blog (justaddwater.dk): [Firefox Tip For Framebuster JavaScript](http://justaddwater.dk/2007/10/22/firefox-tip-for-framebuster-javascript/).

Comment: Well, I see this is an old answer... just for the record: ["Is the user.js:capability.policy gone for good?"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1000843) — "It's gone."

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable using a *debugging* feature present in Firefox, the [watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) method works for me:

```
document.watch('location', function() {
    return '#';
});
```

I'm not sure about the applicability of the warnings about performance, etc. over at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch), perhaps someone has some insight into these in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) add-on for Firefox is designed to do exactly that.

Comment: I don't know how to configure it to remove inline scripts.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual script you want to block?

Comment: Actually, greasemonkey will not do that if the script block is inline. Se my additional answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the [YesScript extention](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/yesscript/).

YesScript lets you make a blacklist of sites that aren't allowed to run JavaScript.